# typescript error when using same event handler for two types of events

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a function that takes two different event objects one for touchscreen and the other for mouse input. TypeScript shows an error when accessing types only available to one of the events.

```
const desktopDragHandler = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement> | React.TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement>
) => {
        //depending on touch screen or mouse we have different properties
        let position = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        if (e.type === "touchmove") { //we have a touch event
            let evt = typeof e.originalEvent === "undefined" ? e : e.originalEvent;
            let touch = evt.touches[0] || evt.changedTouches[0];
            position.x = touch.pageX;
            position.y = touch.pageY;
        } else { //we have a mouse event
            position.x = e.clientX;
            position.y = e.clientY;
        }
}
```

ts shows error when accessing `e.originalEvent` and `e.clientX or e.clientY`. how to resolve the type error here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const desktopDragHandler = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement> | React.TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement>
) => {
        //depending on touch screen or mouse we have different properties
        let position = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        if (e instanceof React.TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement>) { //we have a touch event
            let evt = typeof e.originalEvent === "undefined" ? e : e.originalEvent;
            let touch = evt.touches[0] || evt.changedTouches[0];
            position.x = touch.pageX;
            position.y = touch.pageY;
        } else { //we have a mouse event
            position.x = e.clientX;
            position.y = e.clientY;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript isn't smart enough to know that `e.type === "touchmove"` is the differentiator between the two types, you have to typecast it manually:

```
let evt = typeof (e as React.TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement>).originalEvent === "undefined" ? e : (e as React.TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement>).originalEvent;

position.x = (e as React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>).clientX;
position.y = (e as React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>).clientY;
```

Next time please create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'm just guessing what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this way. here is modal component. handled two mouse events closing and save button click. try this.

```
import React, { FC, MouseEventHandler } from "react";
import styles from './Modal.module.scss'

interface ModalProps {
  modalTitle: String,
  handleModalSaveClick?: MouseEventHandler
  handleModalCancelClick?: MouseEventHandler
}

const Modal: FC<ModalProps> = ({handleModalSaveClick, modalTitle, 
handleModalCancelClick} : ModalProps) => {

return (
  <div className="modal fade show" id="exampleModalLong" role="dialog" aria- 
  labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true" style={{ display: "block", paddingRight: 
  "17px", opacity: 1 }}>
    <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <h5 className="modal-title" id="modal">{modalTitle}</h5>
          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
            label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body">
            
        </div>
        <div className="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data- 
           dismiss="modal" onClick={handleModalCancelClick}>Close</button>
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick= 
           {handleModalSaveClick}>Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 )
}

export default Modal
```